# Embedding JavaScript Engine into Windows Phone applications

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8.1, chakra

I'm searching a way to use a JavaScript engine inside my Windows Phone application but I don't want to build a web application. Plus I have some trouble to find official support for those kinds of information.

I found [this hack](https://iobservable.net/blog/2014/09/10/embedding-chakra-javascript-engine-on-windows-phone/) to inject Chakra in WP apps but apps won't pass Microsoft Windows Store certification requirements so this is not acceptable.

It's my first step to understanding WP apps, sorry if my question is trivial but I was wondering, is there any way to do this properly?

Comment: I thought win8 apps were already written in WinJS. anyway, you can just use cordova.

Comment: I'm aware of Cordova but my application is very specific and sadly I would like to avoid this solution :/

Comment: What do you mean by including a Java script engine in the app? As noted, you can write a natively html/JavaScript ASP on WP8.1. You can host HTML and JavaScript in a xaml app with a WebView control (this is essentially what Cordova does on WP8 and other platforms without native HTML app support)

Comment: Some kind of equivalent to JavascriptCore for iOS or rhino for Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The Chakra APIs are not approved for store apps at this time.